# Can I create an instance of a COM struct in javascript?

Tags: javascript, com, struct, com-interop, wsh

I'm writing a script in Javacript that is run from the command line using **cscript.exe**.

I have the following `struct` defined in a .NET assembly exposed to COM.

Definition in IDL:

```
typedef [uuid(CA667ABD-C702-49DD-BC23-E9A7F75081E5), version(1.0),
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "MyApp.TestStruct")
]
struct tagTestStruct {

MyEnum MyEnumValue;

DATE Start;

} TestStruct;
```

I can instantiate COM objects from Javascript using `WSH.CreateObject()` fine. However, is it possible to somehow create an instance of a COM struct from Javascript?

Comment: You want to use the Windows Scripting Host from JavaScript? Without some kind of ActiveX wrapper I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Cory - Ermm... not sure we're on the same page. I've updated my question to try and make it clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Isn't it more JScript than JavaScript?

Comment: After a little research, the best guess I can give you is that you should try this: `var myTest = new ActiveXObject("MyApp.TestStruct");` The scripting host needs a wrapper around your .NET COM object, and `ActiveXObject` is supposed to be able to do that.

Comment: I think `new ActiveXObject` is similar to `WSH.CreateObject`. I was able to use it to instantiate objects fine, but it was failing with `Automation server can't create object` when trying it with a struct.

Comment: Perhaps you need to give your struct a constructor?

Comment: Going from memory, I think COM interop only works with default constructors and you can only define constructors that take parameters on a struct in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it cannot be done.